# Vibrate with humming sound

Tags: nissan, cooling-system, vibration

I recently notice there is vibration with humming sound coming from my 2017 Nissan Pathfinder. When I start the car and leave it idle I don't hear any vibration with humming sound from front driver and front passenger side. But soon as I drove it around and parked in park drive. I feel would the virbration humming inside the car on the wheel and passenger side would hear the humming. It would sound like in sequence humm humm humm. The humming is not loud I would say it sound like small phone virbation. So far nothing is wrong with the car is just annoying sometimes when I put it on idle.

Any advice would be great appreciated!

Thank you!